# Install pip directory

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7

I am trying to execute sudo easy_install pip in my MAC OS X terminal but without success. I have python 3.7 installed but when I execute the previous sentence it gives the following error, as it goes to the predetermined version of the machine. How can I fix it?

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-1134.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you confirm that the directory mentioned in the error message definitely exists on your system?

Comment: Hi, thank you! The directory doesn't exist. It seems that it is ponting to 2.7 when it should be using 3.7. I have the following directory /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7

Comment: Sounds like you may have a version mismatch issue here, are you sure you have the right version of the installer (and/or of the thing you're trying to install)?

Comment: Yes, I have the right version. Is there anyway to disable Python 2.7 in the terminal so it could recognize 3.7 by default?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Hopefully someone else will chip in.

Comment: Check whether you have `easy_install3` available and try installing with it. However, `pip` should be already bundled in your Python 3.7 installation - check it with `python3.7 -m pip --version`.